# locate specific drive after failure in zfs pool

Tags: disk, zfs

I have a pool that had a drive fail and zfs is being stupid about it.  I added a disk which ended up going to /dev/sdl  I used the disk by id to add it in and due to that after the other drive failed during or just before a reboot i get the following line.

---

5642991870772164099                        UNAVAIL      0     0     0  was /dev/sdl1

---

any idea how to get the info to find what the serial number of 5642991870772164099 is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a Linux system, if the drive is still nominally functional, then `lsblk` likely will work:

```
$ lsblk -do name,model,serial /dev/sdl
NAME MODEL            SERIAL
sdl  ST6000NM0125-1YY ZADAEV8S
```

FreeBSD users would use `diskinfo`:

```
$ diskinfo -s da11
WD-WMC1S5694795
```

OTOH, if you're unsure whether that UUID still associates with `/dev/sdl`, you could search the `/dev/disk/` tree and `grep` for the UUID you're looking for:

```
$ find /dev/disk/ -ls | grep 5642991870772164099
  484  0 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 10 Jun 8 22:24 /dev/disk/by-uuid/5642991870772164099 -> ../../sdl
```

Comment: sadly it looks like that number is an internal thing in zfs and nothing to do with the linux method of displaying partition/disk info. I will have to see what happens when using scsi-xxx or wwn-0x.... nvme-eui.xxx naming when creating pools.

Comment: see https://superuser.com/questions/1732532/zfs-disk-drive-letter-changed-how-to-reimport-by-id/1732542?noredirect=1#comment2680547_1732542 export and import of a pool with known good drives and a shifted drive letter like above allows zfs to find it again. ls -collor /dev/disk/by-id/   > /disklayout.txt  will give you a listing to go off of if you do so before you have issues.